# Enum deprecated c#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have a deprecated (Obsolete) function which returns an enum, and I have a new function which returns a List of enums.

One of the *enum values* is used only in the deprecated function, so is it possible to set an *enum member* as obsolete (because it can't be in the List)?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`ObsoleteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx)?

Comment: Need to see some code...

Comment: @BoltClock why? I just want to set an enum as obsolete...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Sure, you can:

```
public enum EE
{
    A,

    [Obsolete]
    B
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Actually, it is possible to generate either compiler warnings or compiler errors.

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    A,
    [Obsolete("Not in use anymore")]
    B,
    [Obsolete("Not in use anymore", true)]
    C,
}

public class Class1
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        TestEnum t1 = TestEnum.A; //Works just fine.
        TestEnum t2 = TestEnum.B; //Will still compile, but generates a warning.
        TestEnum t3 = TestEnum.C; //Will no longer compile. 
    }
}
```

This will work wherever you use an [Obsolete] attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this on an enum but something like this might work:

```
[Obsolete("Please use ... instead!")]
public enum MyEnum
{
  One,
  Two,
  Three
}
```

Comment: I suggest you allow several days or weeks for a real answer to appear, before posting a guess.  Actually, why not test your guess instead of posting it, so you could post either a real answer or nothing.

Comment: Obviously putting the `Obsolete` attribute on the whole `enum` is not the same as putting it on a single value. It seems that OP want to exclude a particular `enum` value.